# Move QToolButton to different layouts by just pressing it?

Tags: c++, qt

I have here two different layouts, and one QToolButton. My goal is to transfer that button between the two layouts when I click it. I figured this code would work,

snippet:

```
void DominionLinux::on_toolButton_clicked(string state)
{
    if (state=="Disabled"){
        ui->verticalLayout_Enabled->addWidget(ui->toolButton);
        state = "Enabled";
    }
    else if (state=="Enabled"){
        ui->verticalLayout_Disabled->addWidget(ui->toolButton);
        state = "Disabled";
    }
}
```

By default, state == "Disabled". When I test the UI in QTCreator, the first time I click, it works; the button dissapears from one template, and appears on the other. The second time I click when its on the other template, it doesn't. When compiling, I get this warning:
*QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_toolButton_clicked(string)*

Any ideas why the slot stops working?

Comment: Show the whole relevant code? "*QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_toolButton_clicked(string)*" -> Why is it looking for the signal name there with the same one as the slot name? You seem to mix signal and slot names. Show the connect line, please! Moreover, why do you wanna disable a QToolButton this rather than as the good practice says?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas why the slot stops working?

You are missing the signal declaration at the place of the connect as the warning also hints. Also, it seems that you are passing either the slot as the signal to the connect method. A signal should not have the same name as a slot in a Qt application.

Other than that, you may wanna reconsider your design about disabling and enabling a button. Putting them into separate layers is not the appropriate way of doing it.

Moreover, you should probably avoid raw strings for representing states in general. It is better to use enumerations, or boolean for "toggle states".

Comment: Thanks; I took your advice and switched to boolean